# How to find the latitude and longitude falls on waypoints using Google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, directions

I have a group of lat and long which are the stops of a bus.

I need to find the user latitude and longitude is falling on the route.

Find the link to my demo [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ragunathan/full/xYPPdY/)

I draw the route using waypoints as well as polylines. Using `containLocation()` function I Can find the user location falls on the route. But it works somewhere in polylines. I need to make this working on waypoints.

If you click near polyline you will get a red circle or blue triangle. Red indicates the point not falling on the route. Blue indicates the point is falling on the route

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let me get this right, so you want to attach an event listener to the black line so that it exibit the same behaviour of the polyline on a click event?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your sample and your code is not following the logic you describe, this is because you are using the wrong `containLocation()` method this is to see if your location is inside a polygon.

Since you are using a polyine you should use the `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()` method instead. See the [Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/#poly)

As for being able to click on or very close to the waypoint that is impossible because there are no options to make the waypoint object unclickable like with markers at the moment.